# "ORA-12154:TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified" on Mac in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

Connecting through Oracle SQL Developer(version 18.2.0.183) using wallet files(cwallet.sso and ewallet.p12) we are getting the following error “ORA-12154:TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified “when we test the connection via Advanced connection type in SQL Developer. We are using “jdbc:oracle:oci:/@NAME”. We are able to connect using SQLPLUS using “sqlplus /@NAME”. This is on a Mac(High Sierra) with the Instant Client Version 12.2.0.1.0.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html

We have the TNSNAMES.ora and SQLNET.ora files configured and the wallet is set and working fine with SQLPLUS.

Is there anything we should look at to troubleshoot this further? Or any workarounds you might suggest?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: If you change the connection type from Advanced to TNS, does your "NAME" show up in the list of Network Aliases?

Comment: @kfinity Yes, it does show up.

Answer (score 1):

Same advice I gave on the OTN forums -

make sure SQL Developer is reading the TNSNAMES file you think it is.

```
show tns
connect hr/oracle@orcl  -- execute in a sqlworksheet with F5

TNS Lookup locations
--------------------
1.  USER Home dir
    C:\Users\jdsmith

Location used:
-------------
    C:\Users\jdsmith

Available TNS Entries
---------------------
LISTENER_ORCL12C
ORCL
ORCL12C
Connected.
Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected
```

If that fails, try EZCONNECT syntax

connect hr/oracle@server:port/SID

Also, there is a TNS connection type you can use. If OCI is enabled in preferences, your connection will be 'thick' and use sqlnet and tnsnames ora files.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I am unable to connect so how would I open a SQL Worksheet? The only thing I can do is open one without a connection. When I execute the code it prompts me for a username and password that I don't have with the wallet files.

Comment: If you don't have another database to connect to, use SQLcl with nolog to run the command.

Comment: @TomHenricksenComcast I suggest you check your advanced preferences for database in sqldev, check Use Oracle Home and Use OCI. then define your connection using TNS and NOT advanced, and try again.

Comment: @TomHenricksenComcast also make sure sqldev preferences tnsnames directory is set to /Users/thenri921/instantclient_12_2/network/admin

Comment: When I switch back to TNS it works. Does that mean my wallet file isn't being found by SQLDeveloper? I do have the tnsnames directory set to /Users/thenri921/instantclient_12_2/network/admin.

Comment: @TomHenricksenComcast if the wallet was no good, i think you'd get a completely different error